# CSS buttons getting stuck on bottom of page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a dashboard for my application, however for some reason the buttons I have created are stuck to the bottom of the page and no matter how much tinkering I do with the margins and padding they never seem to move at all. I will post the HTML and Style sheet below.

```
<header>
    <h1 class="logo">Logo</h1>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Creation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Active Proxies</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tester</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

</header>
<div class="content">
    <h2>Datacenter Providers</h2>
</div>

  <button class="btn btn1">AWS</button>
  <button class="btn btn2">Google</button>
  <button class="btn btn3">Linode</button>
  <button class="btn btn4">Digital Ocean</button>
  <button class="btn btn5">Vultr</button>
  <button class="btn btn6">Upcloud</button>

<style>@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:300,600');


.btn{
  border:1px solid #FDB927;
  background: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "montserrat";
  cursor: pointer;
  /*margin: 10px; */
  transition: .8;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.btn1,.btn2,.btn3{
  color:#FDB927;
  margin-bottom: 1800px;
}


.btn::before{
  content: "";
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  width:100px;
  height:0%;
  background:#552583;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: .8s;
}
.btn1::before,.btn2::before,.btn3::before{
  bottom:0;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
}

.btn1:hover::before,.btn2:hover::before,.btn3:hover:before{
  height: 180%;
}

h2{
  color:white;
  margin-top: -1200px;
  margin-right: 1200px;
}

:root {
  --background: #552583;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #222;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.content {
  height: 200vh;
  background-image: url(//unsplash.it/1000/1000);
  background-color: #000000;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  background-size: cover;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}


header {
  background: var(--background);
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
}




nav {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: var(--background);
  width: 100%;
  transform: scale(1, 0);
  transform-origin: top;
  transition: transform 400ms ease-in-out;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-left: 1em;
}

nav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 150ms ease-in-out;
}

nav a:hover {
  color:#FDB927;
}



@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .nav-toggle-label {
    display: none;
  }

  header {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr auto minmax(600px, 3fr) 1fr;
  }

  .logo {
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
  }

  nav {
     all: unset;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    transition: none;
    transform: scale(1,1);
    background: none;
    top: initial;
    left: initial;

    grid-column: 3 4;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
  }

  nav ul {
    display: flex;
  }

  nav li {
    margin-left: 3em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }

  nav a {
    opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
  }

  nav a::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 5px;
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: -.75em;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: scale(0, 1);
    transition: transform ease-in-out 250ms;
  }

  nav a:hover::before {
    transform: scale(1,1);
  }
}

</style>
```

I am trying to get the buttons to align right under the header that says Datacenter Providers, but they are stuck to that gray bar on the bottom of the screen. The first 3 buttons are the only ones with any effects on them, I wanted to figure out the alignment before I added effects to the other 3.

Answer (score 0):

Just place the buttons in the same div as your h2 header.

```
<div class="content">
    <h2>Datacenter Providers</h2>
  <button class="btn btn1">AWS</button>
  <button class="btn btn2">Google</button>
  <button class="btn btn3">Linode</button>
  <button class="btn btn4">Digital Ocean</button>
  <button class="btn btn5">Vultr</button>
  <button class="btn btn6">Upcloud</button>
</div>
```

It's probably a good idea to have them in their own container.

```
<div class="content">
    <h2>Datacenter Providers</h2>
    <div class="buttons>

     <button class="btn btn1">AWS</button>
     <button class="btn btn2">Google</button>
     <button class="btn btn3">Linode</button>
     <button class="btn btn4">Digital Ocean</button>
     <button class="btn btn5">Vultr</button>
     <button class="btn btn6">Upcloud</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you have a div with a `height 200vh`, aka, [2 times the window browser](https://tipue.com/blog/css3-vw-vh/);

```
.content {
  height: 200vh;
  background-image: url(//unsplash.it/1000/1000);
  background-color: #000000;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  background-size: cover;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
```

And yours buttons are out/on the bottom of this content, i imagine that the div with `content` class is your page itself, so put all of others elements (like the buttons) inside of this div.